# Listening to all form submit events, including dynamically added forms

Tags: javascript

I'd like to listen to the form submit event on all forms on the page, including any forms that are added dynamically (e.g. expanding a login button into a login form).

The only way I can think of to do this is to constantly check for forms on the page using a setTimeout type call. Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery for this

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
  //your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a listener on form submit on all forms, and when every the content of page updated you should register a listener again for all new form or re-initialize your code again regarding your page. See the following example:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    // forms[i].removeEventListener('submit',functionName);                 
    forms[i].addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
           /* your work */
           // this.removeEventListener('submit',arguments.callee); 
    });
}
```

Then every time you add a new form elements or update your page contents you can run the code again  or attach the listener to newly created form only.

if you decide to run the code on page you should first remove the previous attached listener function by

1. keep a reference's variable of the function before attach it and use the reference to remove them. `forms[i].removeEventListener('submit',referenceToFunction);`
2. Inside the listener function use the following line to remove previous one. `this.removeEventListener('submit',arguments.callee);`